# PythonAnywhere – How do I use the modules I install?

Tags: pythonanywhere

I'm confused by how I'm supposed to install/use new modules in PythonAnywhere.

For instance, I installed the module ephem in Bash console with

```
pip3.6 install --user ephem
```

Everything went alright. If I run the above command again it says;

```
Looking in links: /usr/share/pip-wheels 
Requirement already satisfied: ephem in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (3.7.7.0)
```

However, when I try to use it in my script I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/krollibrius/montaulieu.py", line 7, in <module> import ephem ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ephem'
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you used the wrong python version, try adding

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

to your script. I find that most of the time I install packages to the wrong version. 
Another solution could be to use the command `pythonwithversionnumber -m pip install --user ephem`. Replace pythonwithversionnumber with the command you used to run your script

Comment: Amazing, thank you. Simply running my script with `python3.6 script.py` in the Bash console solved the issue.